100% CPU usage when rendering with OptiX GPU only

Specs ^ gpu is 4090
Scene is not complex at all under a million faces, only 3 objects some glass material...

Blender version: 4.2.2 LTS
Render settings correct. I have no simulations or volumetrics in the scene.
Why is it using so much CPU and almost no GPU?

Why Feature Set Experimental? Do you use any adaptive Subsurface Division modifiers?

Yep I use adaptive sub and some material displacement shenanigans.

@BenedictsForester You did not mention Adaptive Subdivision in your question. The standard subdivision can be handled by GPU and CPU, the Adaptive Subdivision though is calculated by the CPU as far as I remember and can consume a lot of resources.
